# Find all f continuous functions that satisfy $f'(t) = f(t) + \int_{0}^{1} f(t) dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, problem-solving

I started this problem making its derivative and I obtained:
$$ f''(t) = f'(t) $$
The thing here is that I don't know what's next or if I should try another way to solve this.
Any idea/hint?

Comment: The derivative of $\int_0^1 f(t) dt$ is $0$, not $f(1)$

Comment: That's because when you "do" the integral, it is a constant, right?

Comment: If you know that f(1) equals, maybe it could help if you added f'(t) to both sides

Comment: Yes, the integral is a real number. It's not a function.

Comment: River Li, the equality $f'(t)=f(t)+\int_0^1 f(t)dt$ implies that $f'$ is differentiable, because it is equal to a differentiable function.

Comment: @Mark  Yes, your are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer for the question in the title: Let $c=\int_0^{1}f(t)dt$. Then the equation becomes $f'(t)=f(t)+c$. This can be written as $(e^{-t}f(t))'=e^{-t} (f'(t)-f(t))=ce^{-t}$ so we get $e^{-t}f(t)=-ce^{-t}+d$ where $d$ is  a constant. Thus $f(t)=-c+de^{t}$ Now integrate this from $0$ to $1$ to see that  $d=\frac {2c} {e-1}$. Conclusion: $f(t)=-c+\frac {2c} {e-1} e^{t}$ is  solution for every real number $c$.

Comment: This doesn‘t work because $c$ depends on $f$. The solutions can be found by noting $f'(t)=C \exp(t)$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch But the function $f(t)=e^t+\frac{1-e}{2}$ is solution.

Comment: @DiegoMath Thanks, I forgot the integration constant when passing from $d/dx f$ to $f$, now fixed (I wasn't able to fix my now obsolete comment as the answer was briefly deleted)

Comment: @DiegoMath I have edited my answer.

Comment: I'm a little confused on how did you passed from $e^{-t}(f'(t) - f(t)) = ce^{-t}$ to $e^{-t}f(t) = -ce^{-t} + d$.

Comment: I just integrated the equation $\frac d {dt} (e^{-t} f(t))=ce^{-t}$.

Comment: I get it. I have another question. How did you infer that you had to add that $e^{-t}$ multiplying both sides?

Comment: That is a standard trick in the theory of ordinary differential equations. $e^{-t}$ is called the 'integrating factor'.  @SocietyViper

Comment: When I integrated $f(t)$, I obtained $-c + d(e-1)$. Then, $d = \frac{c}{e-1}$

Comment: @SocietyViper If you integrate $f(t)=-c+de^{t}$ from $0$ to $1$ you get $c=-c+d(e-1)$ or $2c=d(e-1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Like it was mentioned in the comments to the OP, by differentiation you get that $f'' - f' = 0$, a linear differential equation with general solution
$$
f(t)=c_1 + c_2 e^t.
$$

So, any function satisfying the proposed. relation is of this form. Conversely, if $f(t)=c_1+c_2 e^t$, then
$$
f'(t)-f(t)-\int_0^1 f(t) dt =$$
$$ c_2 e^t -c_1- c_2 e^t -[c_1 t +c_2 e^t]_0^1 = c_2 e^t-c_1- c_2 e^t-c_1-c_2 e+c_2 = -2c_1 -c_2(e-1),
$$

which is zero if $-2c_1-c_2(e-1)=0$, i.e. $ c_1 = \frac{1-e}{2} c_2$. finally, the solutions are of the form
$$
\frac{1-e}{2} c_2 + c_2 e^t.
$$

Comment: But the function $f(t)=e^t+\frac{1-e}{2}$ is solution, how to explain this?

Comment: If $f$ is a constant then the constant has to be $0$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Sure!! Major fail!!

Comment: @PierreCarre Yes, because the functional equation is another, look the title of the OP's question.